# Extend lifetime of struct to exceed that of another struct

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a lexer for HTML, which requires swapping between states. Because states have to store data, I decided to make each state a struct. The problem is dealing with the lifetime of said state, because it requires storing references to previous states.

Currently, I have the following system:

```
pub struct Lexer<'a> {
    input: Peekable<Chars<'a>>,
    state: Box<dyn LexerState>,
}

trait LexerState {
    fn next_token(&mut self, lexer: &mut Lexer) -> Token;
}

pub struct DataState {}

impl LexerState for DataState {
    fn next_token(&mut self, lexer: &mut Lexer) -> Token {
        lexer.state = Box::new(CharacterReferenceState { return_state: &lexer.state });
        lexer.state.next_token(lexer)
    }
}

pub struct CharacterReferenceState<'a> {
    return_state: &'a Box<dyn LexerState>,
}

impl<'a> LexerState for CharacterReferenceState<'a> {
    fn next_token(&mut self, lexer: &mut Lexer) -> Token {}
}
```

(for the sake of brevity, I've excluded irrelevant code)

This gives the error: "`lexer` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement"

From what I understand, this means I need some guarantee that lexer is valid for the whole time LexerState is valid, because if lexer is invalid, then the state is invalid. From my research, it seems like 'static lifetime would fix this problem, but that raises a few concerns:

1. Can I fix this issue without static/is there a better design pattern for this?
2. Will the static lifetime variable be properly invalidated and freed after the parsing is complete?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c25e22c219456dea8fa6429bf4c01630

Comment: Make the trait specify a lifetime that corresponds with the implementing struct lifetime on `&mut self` (`&'a mut self`)

Comment: You're storing a reference to a field in that same field? Consider owning the `Box` and using https://docs.rs/replace_with/latest/replace_with/.

Comment: I want to reference the original value, not the updated one. Trying to move it gives an error, and I just now realized that the reference probably isn't just the original

Comment: It looks like you're taking a reference to a value (`lexer.state`) and then overwriting that value with a new value, which contains that reference. The new value will therefore be self-referential, which both isn't what you want, and isn't allowed (as written). I think that `CharacterReferenceState::return_state` should not be a reference. It also looks like the design might be a lot simpler if you just use a stack instead of what amounts to a linked list.

Comment: Your right on the first part, it shouldn't of been a reference, the error made me focus on the wrong part. As for the linked list design, that's what it looks like the HTML Standard wants, but I might swap to a stack if it turns out that works.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the compiler error was a red herring and the actual problem was the self-referential reference. To fix this, I just transferred ownership of the Box instead.